# Instalacion de nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tengo el siguiente problema, quizas alguien pueda ayudarme.
Estoy instalando nodejs en windows 10, la instalacion se concreto con exito en el disco principal (disco C), el problema se genera cuando desde visual studio code abro la terminal integrada y quiero verificar la version de node con node --version, me arroja un error el cual adjunto a continuacion:

> node : El término 'node' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o
>   programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de
>   acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.

Cabe aclarar que el proyecto en el cual estoy tratando de verificar este comando esta en el disco D y no en el C, eso tendra alguna relacion con el problema? Cuando verifico la version de node desde el cmd global este comando funciona correctamente.

Comment: Reinicia visual studio code

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de pasarme a windows despues de años de usar linux y es otro mundo jaja gracias por la data, era un error muy de novato jej.

Comment: De nada amigo para servirte,  si te funciono alguien que sepa como cerrar la pregunta podemos darla como cerrada,  tecnicamente una respuesta a esta pregunta no seria valida segun reglas de la comunidad. Asi que habra que cerrarla (darla por concluida).